# How to use `boost::range` iterators with standard iterators

Tags: c++, boost, iterator, std, boost-range

I have functions that take in `std::vector` iterators, as in

```cpp
typedef std::vector<Point> Points;

Points ConvexHull(Points::const_iterator first, Points::const_iterator last);
```

I usually pass the `std` iterators to them, but occasionally I need to work with `boost` iterators, such as `boost::join`'s range iterator. How should I change the parametrizations of my functions, ideally without templates, so that they accept both iterators? Moreover, how do I indicate in each type which iterator concepts I need?

I tried looking at the `boost::range` documentation but it's overwhelmingly confusing for me and I don't know where to start.

For example, I couldn't find the difference between `boost::range_details::any_forward_iterator_interface` and `boost::range_details::any_forward_iterator_wrapper`, and whether I should use either of those to specify that I need a forward iterator.

---

**Edit:**

If I use `boost::any_range`, how can I pass non-const lvalue references?

For example:

```cpp
template<typename T>
using Range = boost::any_range<T, boost::random_access_traversal_tag, 
                               T, std::ptrdiff_t>;


f(Range<Point> &points);  // defined elsewhere

// -------------

vector<Point> vec;
f(vec);  // error; cannot bind non-const lvalue reference to unrelated type
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should strongly consider using a template. Doing so let's the compiler keep useful information about what operations are actually occurring, which greatly helps it generate optimised output. The `std::` convention is to name the type parameter for the concept required. E.g.

```
template< class BidirIt, class UnaryPredicate > // anything bidirectional (which includes random access)
BidirIt std::partition( BidirIt first, BidirIt last, UnaryPredicate p );
```

If you really don't want a template, you still shouldn't name anything in a `detail` namespace. Something like

```
#include <boost/range/any_range.hpp>

using PointRange = boost::any_range<Point, boost::random_access_traversal_tag>; // or another traversal tag.
using PointIterator = PointRange::iterator;
```

You will likely need to pass `PointRange &` *less frequently* than, say, `int *&`. Almost always passing by value is the correct behaviour. It is cheap to copy, as it holds a `begin` and `end` iterator from the *Range* that it was constructed from, nothing more.

Answer (score 4):

[boost-range](/questions/tagged/boost-range) has the `any_range` for this purpose and it suits both purposes for your case.

https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/libs/range/doc/html/range/reference/ranges/any_range.html

From your example it would look like this:

```
#include <boost/range/any_range.hpp>

typedef boost::any_range<Point,
                         boost::bidirectional_traversal_tag,
                         Point,
                         std::ptrdiff_t
                        > PointRange;
```

Comment: Thanks! Yes, I believe this is what I'm looking for. But is there a way to access the range's `size`? It seems `size` is undefined for `boost::any_range<Point, boost::bidirectional_traversal_tag, Point, std::ptrdiff_t>`;

Comment: You can use the free function `boost::size`

Comment: just call `boost::size(range)`

Comment: Thanks! And is there a way to pass non-const lvalue references? (see edit above)

Comment: @Anakhand its more of a c++ thing than boost::range - that is not possible unless you vector is of the range type (ie. inheritance) - you need to create the range object somehow, that is remove the reference - i like to think of a range as just a pair of iterators.